# Angular Material 2 routerlink inside datatable

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-material, angular-material2, angular6

I have a data table and I'm trying to assign an `<a>` around a participants name `<td>` that would take the user when clicked to a new component.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let Participant"> <a routerlink="/participants/userId">{{Participant.name}}</a> </td>
</ng-container>
```

It's not showing an error or anything, however, it's not making the `<td>` clickable, it's completely ignoring the `routerLink`, if I assign an `href` to the `<a>` it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of handling this will be based on (click) event.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let Participant"> 
  <span style="cusor:pointer;" (click)="navigate(Participant)">
        {{Participant.name}}</span>  </td>
</ng-container>
```

In your typescript code:

```ts
private navigate(product){
  this.router.navigate(['/participants', product]); //we can send product object as route param
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it this way, and userId must be defined as an angular variable.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let Participant" routerLink="/participants/{{userId}}"> {{Participant.name}}
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

Thanks

Comment: I recommend this because it reduces boilerplate code. Works like charm as well.